# Where do third-party icons appear in Windows 7 Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, icons, control-panel

I have various third-party settings icons for proprietry hardware that appear in the Control Panel as icons in Windows XP. When I reinstall the system with Windows 7 (including all latest drivers etc), when Control Panel is configured to use the default Category view mode, is it possible to get to those icons? I can get to them by switching the view mode to large or small icons but I'd rather keep with the category view. Is there any way to get to those icons?

Note that the icons are there in icon view so they are installed, I just want to know where they are put in the Caegory view, if they are accessible at all throug that view.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click a category title (large green text) in the initial view it shows you all the Control Panel applets in that category, including some third-party ones. For instance, the Flash Player settings manager appears in the *System and Security* category and has its normal icon. However, the categories themselves (System and Security, User Accounts etc.) [are fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so third parties cannot add their own.

[image]

If a Control Panel applet did not have a category set when it was installed then it seems that you cannot view it through the category view and must use the icon view. But in some cases it is possible to manually set a category by [editing registry entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/hh127450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). **You should not touch the registry if you do not know what you are doing though**.

Comment: For example, Java is under "Programs", NVIDIA Control Panel is under "Hardware and Sound"...

Comment: It's possible for items to appear in multiple categories. So the nVidia settings are also found under *Appearance and Personalization*.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much how I thought it would work. The driver config program is for very niche hardware and I guess they just haven't added their CP app to a category yet. Oh well.